# HTML web form mailto not working issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help, I am new to HTML5. I build a HTML5 web form and try to use mailto function to send out. But when I try to do it on my android device with chrome browser, it shows:

> *Webpage not available*

Anyone can help ?

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:myname@gmail.com" enctype="text/plain">       
  <p>
    <label for ="firstname" class="text">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
  </p>      
  <p>
    <label for ="lastname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
  </p>    
  <p>
    <label for ="hkid">HK Identity Card:</label>
    <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="sex" class="select">Sex:</label>
    <select name="sex" id="sex" data-native-menu="false">
      <option value="option1">Male</option>
      <option value="option2">Female</option>
    </select>
  </p>                                
  <p>
    <label for="mobile"> Mobile:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
  </p> 
  <p>
    <label for="hometel">Resident Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="hometel" id="hometel" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
  </p>     
  <p>
    <label for ="date">Appointment Date(DD-MM-YYYY)</label>
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="" />
  </p>         
  <p>
    <label for="session" class="select">Session :</label>
    <select name="session" id="session" data-native-menu="false">
      <option value="option1">AM</option>
      <option value="option2">PM</option>
    </select>
  </p>  

  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />      
</form>
```

Comment: That is not a good way of implmenting html mailto. Please take a look at : stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body/13415988 and stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto/4782084

Answer (score 1):

[`mailto:` as a form action simply is not well supported](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html).

Use an HTTP(S) form action and send the email from your server instead of the user's (possibly non-existent) email client.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to use the control panel and go to folder options.

Open the "File Types" tab.

There find the entry "URL: MailTo Protocol" ... highlight it and click "advanced".

Now highlight "open" and click "edit".

You will probably find outlook express as the mailto program.

Change "application to use" as follows: 
"C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://mail.google.com/mail?extsrc=mailto&url=%1

The path within the quote marks is whatever is the correct path on your machine to chrome.exe.

The Application: chrome

That's it.

Comment: Outlook express? On an **Android device**?! Solutions that require the end user to reconfigure their system are no good to authors of websites anyway.

Comment: So, which Android phone has control panel?