# mailto function not working on android phones

Tags: html, forms

for some reason my mail to function does not seem to work in android devices.... i'm really confused what to do as it seems to be working fine on windows devices

```
<article class="contact_form"> 
   <h2><i>Reach Me</i></h2>
    <table class="contact-table">
<form action="mailto:sanwal.sahil@yahoo.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="EmailTestForm">


<tr>
    <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="visitor" />
    <br>
    <br>
    </td>
</tr>       
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
         <button type="submit" colspan="1" class="form-submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </td>
  </tr> 



    </form>
     </table>  
</article>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML web form mailto not working issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474533/html-web-form-mailto-not-working-issue)

Answer (score 2):

`mailto:`, in general, has [very unreliable support](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) as a form action. This is likely just one more example of that. You should avoid it entirely in favour of using an HTTPS (or even HTTP) URL with a server side form handler.

---

Additionally, [your form is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table/5967613) in a way that will break it in a number of browsers. Write [valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: yeah even i think i'll move to server side form building